# Ember location 'history' pre4 the correct way

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some problems specifying the Router's location property with ember.js. I have the following code, which works if I do not set the App.Router's location to 'history'. When I set it, when it tries to load the page the console shows the following error : Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL '/test/' - where /test/ is my directory in my /var/www/ . Here is the code:

app.js

```
window.App = Em.Application.create({
title: 'Title'
});


App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
 })

 App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   name: 'test'
 })

 App.IndexAboutView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName: 'index/about'
 })

 App.IndexAboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    str: 'my string'
 })

 App.IndexBioView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName: 'index/bio'
  })

  App.IndexBioController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    str: 'bio text'
 })

 App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
 });

 App.Router.map(function(match){
  this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('bio');
   })
  })
```

And my index file looks like :

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">


        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="navbar-inner">

                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="brand">
                          {{#linkTo "index"}}{{unbound App.title}}{{/linkTo}}   
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index/about">
      This is the str from about : {{str}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index/bio">
      This is the str from bio : {{str}}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the rootURL property on your router. Something like:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  rootURL: '/test',
  location: "history"
});
```

That tells the Router where to start it's relative paths from in the browser history.

Comment: Please refer [code sample with **location: 'history'**](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/37/edit). I have the following questions: 1. Why do I have to specify "rootURL" in Router - otherwise the first page is not rendered? It simply said the /<app> URL is undefined, if I did not specify 'rootURL : /<app>' in Router.reopen? 2. With the history feature of Ember router, every route transition is displayed as a separate URL but bookmarking those URLs will bomb as a simple refresh of those second or third routes results in a 404. How to prevent ember from creating new URLs for the subsequent routes?

Answer (score 0):

Add /test/ to your index path, I added a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/iyexuf/8/edit) instead of /test/ i had to match the default root url of jsbin i.e. `/iyexuf/3/edit`

```
App.Router.map(function(match){
  this.resource('index', { path: '/test/' }, function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('bio');
   })
  })
```

I added a link to about and bio to illustrate the navigation between the three sections (title, about,bio)

```
{{#linkTo "index.about"}}About{{/linkTo}}   
{{#linkTo "index.bio"}}Bio{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: Was it working before setting location to history ? didn't notice ?

Comment: yes it worked. And it's not working if I extend it with /test/

Comment: Ok, but that does not solves the problem. It's as if creating links to other pages. This does not need at all a router. Just until it creates the controllers. There must be a way to connect from the Router's resource too, since without history it works.

Comment: Hmm I dont' see how that worked before, there was no link to display the bio and about templates. Did I miss something ? Anyways i updated the script to illustrate how to use the three links together. See the update above. Let me know if that works

Comment: I dont' understand what's your problem anymore :) can you be more specific ?

Comment: Yes, using your solution I need to create every time I create a menu item a new link. this means I have to type some additional lines and I am specifying the route in two places so if i have to change, I have to change in two places. According to [doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources) using the construct what I used automatically creates the routes, controllers, templates and since it worked without specifying location: 'history' I think it should be able to work if it is specified also.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you display the about/bio templates before, in your html page there no way that happens unless you link to them or you type in the url manually yourself. What you're saying about automatic creation of views, controllers hold true still here. But at some point you need to wire your application in a way or another, if not by directly linking the views in the html page, then it's through the renderTemplate method in the Route.

Comment: just remove the `App.Router.reopen({ location: 'history'});` and use the map as it was: instead of `/test/` just `/` . And yes, I had to type it manually. So what you are saying is I have to make a linkTo every time I expand my menu? It is rather a theoretical question, but I like to do what can be automated automatically. And it does not seem right for me - see my point in if it works with # the int should work without it also.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Ember, it's a browser issue, see http://caniuse.com/history linked through http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/. Your issue is about using pushState to manage history states instead of the history hash with relation to bookmarking ...

Comment: I don't see how is that a browser issue, since both in chrome and firefox one version works the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
})
```

where App is my app constant name, and it comes before `App.Router.map`...